# Problemas al llamar un ejecutable dentro de un controlador en laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, cmd

estoy trantando de llamar un ejecutable `.exe`(a ubicación está añadida en el `PATH` de `WINDOWS`) dentro de un `controller` en `Laravel` usando los métodos `escapeshellarg` y `exec` de la siguiente forma:

```
$escaped_cmd = escapeshellarg('C:\wamp64\www\proyecto\app\Http\Controllers\openalpr_64\alpr.exe samples\us-4.jpg');
$salida=exec($escaped_cmd);
return $salida;
```

y no me devuelve absolutamente nada. Cuando imprimo la variable `$escaped_cmd` me devuelve exactamente lo mismo que se está introduciendo y lo pego directamente al `CMD` me sale esto correctamente.

```
C:^\wamp64^\www^\proyecto^\app^\Http^\Controllers^\openalpr_64^\alpr.exe samples^\us-4.jpg
plate0: 10 results
    - LTM378     confidence: 89.5721
    - LM378      confidence: 83.0723
    - LTM37B     confidence: 81.7983
    - LTH378     confidence: 76.4686
    - LTN378     confidence: 76.053
    - LM37B      confidence: 75.2985
    - LH378      confidence: 69.9688
    - LN378      confidence: 69.5532
    - LTH37B     confidence: 68.6948
    - LTN37B     confidence: 68.2792
```

Además,el método `exec()` funciona muy bien, ya que me devuelve correctamente el `exec('ipconfig') ;`y el `exec('echo hola mundo');`

Mucho menos devuelve error por consola del navegador. Qué puede ser?

Comment: Viste que **exec** puede recibir 3 parámetros,  Véase la documentación   http://php.net/manual/es/function.exec.php

Answer (score 1):

Exec puede recibir 3 parámetros, si solo se proporciona el primero [exec()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.exec.php) retorna la última línea de los resultados del comando.

```
string exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )
```

Quedaría algo así:

```
$escaped_cmd = escapeshellarg('C:\wamp64\www\proyecto\app\Http\Controllers\openalpr_64\alpr.exe samples\us-4.jpg');
$salida = array();
exec($escaped_cmd, $salida);
return $salida;
```